# WebRTC with WebExtension API

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, webrtc, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on

My question is simple, **is Firefox implement WebRTC API with [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) ?**

I developped a library using webrtc which works correctly in chrome/firefox/edge. And now I want to test it in an extension. To do so I use the Webextension API with browser-polyfill package to correctly import the "browser" environment. But regardless of my efforts, no webrtc offers are created in Firefox. It works perfectly on Chrome Extension (not tested on Edge Extension)

My searches lead to this:  (https://trello.com/c/ZjeQt2Rg).
So naturally the answer to my question is No.

If someone has a better/more accurate answer, please feel free to share your knowledge !
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by opening a new very small popup window use there the WebRTC API and communicate from this page to the background WebExtension. It's not a good solution but in my case it was a working solution after weeks of trying.

I hope this can help you too.